# Term for people who are in the same city

Tags: word-choice

I found the term "fellow citizens", but the term I'm looking for should also refer to people who are not be a citizen of the city but are located there.

Comment: Sure, but the right term would also refer to people may not live there.

Comment: I would call them 'visitors'.

Comment: Denizen: an inhabitant or occupant of a particular place.   ------------  Resident: one who resides in a particular place permanently or for an extended period